# Check if arraylist contains only nulls

Tags: java, arraylist

I think there has to be a better way of doing this..
I have a call to a function that returns an ArrayList.
If that ArrayList only returns 10 null items (the default), is there a way of checking this without iterating through all 10 items to see if they are null?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by `ArrayList only returns 10 null items`

Comment: What do you mean by "the default"? If it means that you haven't added anything to it then just use `.isEmtpy()` method.

Comment: why not use the isEmpty() method?

Comment: What's the use of adding null items to the ArrayList?

Comment: I wonder if he is confused by the documentation for the default constructor for ArrayList().  It allocates space for 10 items, but it doesn't place any items, nor nulls, into that space.  `isEmpty()` would be the correct method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, no; there is no other way to tell that an arbitrary ArrayList contains ten instances of `null` than to loop over it and make sure each element is `null`. You can forgo this, of course, if the size() of the list isn't equal to ten.

Answer (score 30):

As of Java 8, you can use [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) like this:

```
boolean nullsOnly = list.stream().noneMatch(Objects::nonNull);
```

Which is equal to:

```
boolean nullsOnly = list.stream().allMatch(x -> x == null)
```

And here you can see the more general way of testing that any list matches a given [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html):

```
list.stream().allMatch(x -> /* Some testing function. */)
```

Comment: Didn't know about "noneMatch" or "allMatch" until now. Thanks for that.

Comment: Used your answer then Intellij suggested to replace to list.stream().allMatch(Objects::isNull)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();

arrayList.isEmpty();
// first call returns true    

arrayList.add(null);
// second call returns false    
Object obj = new Object();

arrayList.add(obj);

arrayList.isEmpty();
// third call returns false
```

Is that what you wanted?

Multiple addition of nulls increments the size by one, but there isn't a concrete "easy way" of finding the number of null objects unless you loop the array list.

Comment: It's not what he's wanted. His list contains ten `null` entries. His point of view is empty, but `isEmpty` would return false.

Comment: Updated my answer to be a little more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to check if the ArrayList is empty? (i.e. `myArrayList.isEmpty()`) or are you trying to check if the ArrayList contains only null references? If you're trying to check if all entries are null then you will need to check each entry...

```
boolean isListOfNulls(List myList){
    for(Object o: myList)
        if(!(o == null))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Because that's where my cursor was when I typed ! :). Either works. On a side note, now I feel the need to benchmark that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Sure, both work, but one is very easy to read, the other one needs to be double checked when reading ;)

Comment: @Mike They almost certainly don't make a difference as they are exactly the same (it is even mentioned somewhere in the JLS).

Answer (score 1):

try with the stream API.

```
boolean haveOnlyNulls = arraylist.stream().noneMatch(object -> object != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check is by using `boolean allMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate);`
This
Returns whether all elements of this stream match the provided predicate. May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result. If the stream is empty then true is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.

```
 boolean hasAllNulls = list.stream().allMatch(Objects::isNull)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the default to an empty ArrayList and use isEmpty(). The present default is senseless.